# Custom toolbar not appearing in preview tab

Tags: android, toolbar

this is a very weird problem that I am facing for quite a lot of time. I was able to fix an issue which prevented any sort of widgets not appearing in an activity preview tab by adding "Base." to the theme. If I test it on my device, I can see my custom toolbar but in Android studio`s preview tab it all appears white. What I have tried:

1- Restarted Android studio
2- Invalidated caches and restarted Android studio
3- Changing app theme to different

[image]

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="#263238"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/refToolbarTitleID"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST TEXT" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I can not properly setup my toolbar. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: from custom toolbar you mean adding the toolbar in your xml?

Comment: please post full xml layout

Comment: @SinaMN75 Yes I have created toolbar.xml file and included in my activity`s xml.

Comment: @JohnJoe Added toolbar xml

Comment: @TaseerAhmad is this full xml ?  Where is the relative layout attribute ?

Comment: @JohnJoe Sorry that was cut out

Comment: Have you added `</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` in last line of your file ?

Comment: Yes, I have added. Apparently, the problem only exists on the android studio level. If I test it on my real device, the custom toolbar appears but in android studio`s preview tab it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to add `</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` at the end of your XML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you using the toolbar in a wrong way, you have to put the toolbar inside a root layout, just like you would do it with buttons or textviews, and then you have to pin it to the top side of the screen.